# onclick is not returning the element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which pops up in a JqueryUI dialog. I want to be able to click on a row in the table and get the information to populate into fields on the main page. For some reason when I click on anything, I keep getting "jquery####" objects that I am unable to select any of the table, tr or td elements.

I have searched here and found nothing about these elements. It's been suggested that you use $(this).find('td') but that is finding a weird element not part of my table.

```
{
    "0": {},
    "1": {},
    "2": {},
    "3": {},
    "4": {},
    "5": {},
    "length": 6,
    "prevObject": {
        "0": {
            "jQuery111003455579954774942": 76
        },
        "context": {
            "jQuery111003455579954774942": 76
        },
        "length": 1
    },
    "context": {
        "jQuery111003455579954774942": 76
    },
    "selector": "td"
}
```

If I only use this, then I get back the following object

```
{
    "0": {
        "jQuery111003455579954774942": 76
    },
    "context": {
        "jQuery111003455579954774942": 76
    },
    "length": 1
}
```

My basic table

```
<br><br>
<h4>Saved Addresses</h4>
<table id='results' border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Prov</th>
      <th>Postal Code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>123 Test St</td>
      <td>Toronto</td>
      <td>ON</td>
      <td>A5A5A5</td>
      <td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</pre>
```

Javascript to create click event

```
<script>

    $('#results tbody tr').click(function() {
      //get <td> element values here!!??
      loadShipper($(this).find('td'));
      //alert($(this).find('td'));
    });
//located on main page where I want to load the TD element information - right now dumping because the object is coming back strange
function loadShipper(obj){
    str = JSON.stringify(obj);
str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4); // (Optional) beautiful indented output.
console.log(str); // Logs output to dev tools console.
alert(str); // Displays output using window.alert()
</script>
```

As long as I can get the TR or TD element, getting the information is easy. I am not sure why the click event is not finding the actual TR or even if I try to get the children, not finding the TD elements which I can iterate over.

Fiddle created duplicating my issue https://jsfiddle.net/dv5ck2o9/

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).find("td")`, not `this.find("td")`

Comment: Updated my question because this.find is an error and $(this).find("td") is what I get back in my first block response with "selector" : "td"

Comment: `$(this).find("td").text()` or, if you're looking to select a specific `<td>` either narrow down your selector, or do something like this: `$($(this).find("td")[0]).text()`

Comment: Find out more about `.text()` here https://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

$(this).find("td").text()

was the solution. It seems .text() is required based on the jquery elements having descendants that are not found from JSON.stringify

Thanks to Joundill for the answer that I can't upvote